# Excel import: How to always look for text file in workbook folder, so path is a variable?

Tags: excel, vba, text, import, path

I've made a macro where I import a text file to Excel (and do other stuff). I would like to give my Excel Workbook to my collegues, therefore I need the code to always get the text file from the folder the Excel workbook is placed in. This is givng me alot of trouble and no solution so far. Any help will be greatly appeciated!
This is what I'm trying, but it's not working.

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
FileName = folderPath & "\stress.rpt"

With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;FileName", _
    Destination:=Range("$M$8"))
```

This is the fixed path, that will only work on my computer.

```
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
     "TEXT;C:\Users\Marg\Dropbox\Blad\stress.rpt", _
    Destination:=Range("$M$8"))
```

I'm sure there must be an easy fix, and I hope some of you out there knows it and can help me on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & FileName, _
    Destination:=Range("$M$8"))
```

p.s: Your way of getting the Filename is correct, but it is better practice to use  `ThisWorkbook` which refers to the wb running the macro, instead of ActiveWorkbook which refers to any open wb that has the focus (your users might get confused if they open another wb while working with yours at the same time..)

```
folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that was very helpfull!!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

Sub ImportText()

Dim FileName As String
Dim folderPath As String
folderPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
FileName = folderPath & "\test.txt"

```
Range("M1").Select
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & FileName, Destination:=Range("$M$1"))
    .Name = "test_4"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

End Sub

Keep in mind, you can add a DialogueBox to navigate to your text file.

```
Sub NavigateToTextFile()
Dim strFileToOpen As String

strFileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.txt* (*.txt*),")

    Workbooks.Open FileName:=strFileToOpen

End Sub
```